# Error while executing the Proc PLS-00103 Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following

Tags: oracle, plsql

I encountered this error when I try to run the given procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE comm_rept (p_manager_sales_pos_id NUMBER)
IS
v_sales_in_dollar NUMBER;
t_TBL_sales_pos_id t_sales_rep.sales_pos_id%rowtype;
t_TBL_commission   t_sales_rep.commission%rowtype;
v_sales_pos_id   t_TBL_sales_pos_id;
v_commission     t_TBL_commission;

CURSOR cur_sales IS
SELECT sales_pos_id,ROUND(((commission*100)/SALES_IN_DOLLAR),2) FROM t_sales WHERE sales_pos_id IN 
            (SELECT sales_pos_id FROM t_sales_rep WHERE manager_sales_pos_id = p_manager_sales_pos_id); 
BEGIN

   OPEN cur_sales;
   FETCH  cur_sales BULK COLLECT INTO v_sales_pos_id,v_commission;
   FORALL i in 1..v_count() = 0
   LOOP
   INSERT INTO t_commission_report (MGR_ID,SALES_POS_ID,COMMISSION) VALUES (p_manager_sales_pos_id,v_sales_pos_id(i),v_commission(i));

END LOOP;
CLOSE cur_sales;
END comm_rept;
/
```

Help me out, I don't want to execute it but want to find out the exact error. Let me know the way to find out the error.

Comment: Can you provide full error with line number

Comment: PLS-00103 : Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following: .(*%&^+/ at mod remainder rem select update with <an exponent (**)> delete insert || execute multiset save merge

Comment: Compile should give you the error and the line number as well, no need to execute

Comment: can you give me some anonymous block to catch the exact error. The error now i have provided might be small that we can overcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [`FORALL`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/forall_statement.htm) has a wrong syntax; it should be something like the following, with no `LOOP`:

```
FORALL I IN 1 .. SOMETHING
    INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE(...)
    VALUES ...
```

Comment: I removed the loop and tried, shows error like "The symbol *" was inserted before "=" to continue

Comment: You missed Aleksej's point, I think. You have `FORALL i in 1..v_count() = 0`. You should have `FORALL i in 1..v_count()` instead. I.e. remove the `= 0`

Comment: Hey Aleksej and boneist... thanks man I got complete error details once I removed the 0, now I can identify what is the major cause. :)